# Application force closes constantly after an update

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, stack-trace, crash-reports

I recently pushed an update for an app, and now I'm getting a lot of crash reports from users about it crashing before even opening the application. I have the stack trace, but I don't recognize any of my classes in it - so I have no idea where to start looking even.

This is the stack trace:

```
v2.0    Dec 16, 2011 11:00:03 AM          17 reports/week              17 reports
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Rect.<init>(Rect.java:72)
at android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable.mutate(ShapeDrawable.java:359)
at android.widget.ImageView.applyColorMod(ImageView.java:1275)
at android.widget.ImageView.onSetAlpha(ImageView.java:290)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2094)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1525)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1261)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1862)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas what the actual culprit could be in here or at least what I should be looking into??

We've changed the minSdkVersion to a higher API, would it be possible that users with a lower API might be trying to update or could they not even download it in that case?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

UPDATE: @LuxuryMode, thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, this is all I'm seeing in the crash report under crash errors in our application account, should I be looking somewhere else? It posts the date and time, the version of the application and the number of reports, followed by this stack trace, over and over.

At the top, there's the following:

```
Exception class     java.lang.NullPointerException
Source method       Rect.<init>()
```

We're trying to register users for C2DM when the application starts - would the application crash if the API level is lower than 8 or would it just fail silently? (though I'm not seeing anything C2DM specific in this stack trace)

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the sdk version. You wouldn't be getting a nullpointer. Getting an exception, means the app is running and an exception was thrown. Are you sure that's all there is in the Log? There should be more, telling you where the exception was thrown. Post the full stack trace, including the part beginning with "caused by..."

Comment: this is not a full stack trace

Comment: this is a full stack trace, I have exactly same mysterious problem :) Btw ruxy, how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but I reproduced this problem and found the solution.

This problem exists for API 15 and below when padding for the ShapeDrawable object is (0, 0, 0, 0) and this object needs mutation. This may happen on `setAlpha(...)` call for ImageView, for example.

The thing is that the old implementations of `ShapeDrawable.setPadding(int, int, int, int)` check parameters for zeros and in this case set the padding Rect to null:

```
public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
{
    if ((left | top | right | bottom) == 0) {
        mShapeState.mPadding = null;
    }
}
```

At the same time the Rect(Rect r) constructor simply crashes on receiving null parameter.

So, the solution is in adding `drawable.setPadding(new Rect());` to avoid the NPE condition.